# open 1GB xml file

Tags: xml, editor, file-handling

Which editor/utility  can open/split  a big XML file (around 1GB).

Notepad++, MS Word fail. Google chrome shows part of the file as plain text and fails to load the rest.

How can I view this file as a formatted file.

Comment: If you are one a unix os, use a command line tool like vim.

Comment: try sublime text, I've opened MySQL dumps before, you might wait several seconds but it will open it.

Comment: UltraEdit can open also any text file with any file size including huge XML files.

Answer (score 2):

If you can read text at 100 characters per second, then reading a gigabyte is going to take you about 8 hours per day for a year. So if you do succeed in loading it into an editor, I don't think you're going to read it all.

So think again about what you really want to do with it. Do you just want to take a peek at the beginning or end of the file? Then use `more` or `tail`. Do you want some kind of analysis or digest? Then query it using XPath or XQuery. Do you want to split it into smaller parts? Use XSLT, especially a streaming XSLT processor like Saxon-EE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a UI-Editor is that the whole document gets into computers memory. If your computer has only 2GB RAM and the file is 4GB large this can lead to problems.

My advice is to use a command-line tool like vim.

Another options is to split the large file in multiple smaller files.